# JVM (Java Transport client) caches the IP address of the DNS entry AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, caching, dns, jvm

NoNodeAvailableException could potentially be related to the fact that the IP address of ELB changes frequently but the JVM (Java Transport client) caches the IP address of the DNS entry of ELB.

Problem is the IP of the ELB which is on AWS might change once in while which we dont have control . When it changes our system fails with a error saying no node found reason being the IP is cache and is still trying lookup with the same IP which is causing the issue . 
For this i got a resolution that is to set "networkaddress.cache.ttl" = "0"  which will tell the JVM not to cache the IP .

My problem is how do i simulate this scenario , because change the IP is not in my control , Can any suggest me a smart way doing it from code (Not the fix part but the testing part)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a value other than `0` because otherwise you'll be flooding the network with DNS requests every time you make a connection, and in some cases, will cause additional delays. Using a number between `5` and `60` would make sense.

If you are verifying the fix, you can use a tool like wireshark to monitor the network and verify that continued connections to the server are making DNS requests and responses for the name. If you want to write an automated test then you'll have to stand up some kind of DNS infrastructure and have that co-ordinate with your tests to cycle between different values.